# how to set default date in MUI X MobileDatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

in our system we migrate from using { DatePicker, DatePickerProps } from "material-ui-pickers-mui5"
to use { MobileDatePicker, MobileDatePickerProps } from "@mui/x-date-pickers"

we have a property called `initialFocusedDate`, I tried to use it and there is no property like that in the new MUI X date pickers.

how can I set an `initial date` for the new MUI X date pickers?